# SQL Server 2017 - SELECT com Metadados duplicados

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-select

Fiz um select utilizando metadados, mas o resultado da minha seleção me trouxe algo parecido com um 'Cross Join'. Mesmo usando GROUP BY e DISTINCT retorna com os valores duplicados. Gostaria de uma ajuda para que os valores retornassem corretamente ... segue o sql:

#### SQL:

```
SELECT distinct

S.name as 'Schema',

T.name as Tabela,

C.name as Coluna,

TY.name as Tipo,

C.max_length as 'Tamanho Máximo', -- Tamanho em bytes, para nvarchar normalmente se divide este valor por 2

C.precision as 'Precisão', -- Para tipos numeric e decimal (tamanho)

C.scale as 'Escala', -- Para tipos numeric e decimal (números após a virgula)

TEP.value as 'Descrição'

FROM sys.columns C 

INNER JOIN sys.tables T
ON T.object_id = C.object_id

LEFT JOIN sys.schemas S
ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id

INNER JOIN sys.types TY
ON TY.user_type_id = C.user_type_id

LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties TEP 
ON T.object_id = TEP.major_id
```

#### Imagem do resultado:

[image: Imagem de explicação:]

Creio que o problema está do ultimo JOIN, quando troco o parâmetro 'TEP.major_id' para 'TEP.minor_id' ele retorna os valores corretos, porém sem as descrições das colunas.

#### Imagem do resultado (usando 'TEP.minor_id'):

[image: imagem 2]

Comment: Não esta duplicado porque os valores da ultima coluna são diferentes. Uma das maneiras de resolver isso é fazendo um select desse select filtrando apenas o que deseja. SELECT * FROM ( seu_select ) A WHERE DESCRICAO = 'o_que_desejar'

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que a junção com a exibição `sys.extended_properties` está incompleta. 
Experimente o seguinte:

```
-- código #1
....
LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties TEP 
     ON T.object_id = TEP.major_id
        and C.object_id = TEP.minor_id
        and TEP.name = 'MS_Description'
```

Não testei, mas espero que seja isto.